# Difference between a JSR223 Sampler and JSR223 PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to Jmeter and vigorously learning.

I wanted to know how JSR223 Sampler and JSR223 PreProcessor are different, can a sampler be used the same way as the preprocessor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General difference is that PreProcessor won't be executed unless it has a sampler in its scope which it will be [triggered](https://www.toolsqa.com/jmeter/pre-processor/) (per sampler)

> Pre-Processor element is defined to alter the settings of Samplers in their scope. It will always execute before the actual sampler request.

Specific difference is that [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) doesn't have `SampleResult` available, so for example you can't execute the following example:

```
SampleResult.setStopTest(true);
```

> The `SampleResult` ResponseData is set from the return value of the script. If the script returns null, it can set the response directly, by using the method `SampleResult.setResponseData(data)`, where data is either a String or a byte array. The data type defaults to "text", but can be set to binary by using the method `SampleResult.setDataType(SampleResult.BINARY)`.
>
> The SampleResult variable gives the script full access to all the fields and methods in the SampleResult. For example, the script has access to the methods `setStopThread(boolean)` and `setStopTest(boolean)`.

Answer (score 3):

JSR223 Sampler is a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), so it will generate a [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) which will appear in the Test Results (unless you call [SampleResult.setIgnore()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) method)

JSR223 PreProcessor cannot be executed per se, you need to connect it to one (or many) Samplers according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so it will be executed before one (or many) samplers. PreProcessors execution time is not reflected in the test results (unless you use a [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) configured to include it)

Both can run an arbitrary code (it's recommended to stick to [Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)) so which one is to use mostly depends on your use case, if you need to conduct the load and measure the time - go for the Sampler, if you need to set up some data - go for the PreProcessor, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitri!! It is clear to me now when to use which one.